# How to recover a file deleted in WSL from explorer.exe?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-recovery

I accessed my Ubuntu mount via \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\user.ssh and deleted a private key I shouldn't have.

I wasn't sure if maybe Windows threw the file in the Recycle Bin, so first I tried recuva with no success.

Everything else that I've read about when it comes to linux and deleted files has been about dismounting the drive and running extundelete or photorec.

How can I go about recovering a file from a WSL mount?

Answer (score 0):

Recovery of deleted files is never certain, of course.  The less you have used the filesystem since deletion, the better the chances.

The way that you would attempt it will depend on whether your instance is WSL1 or WSL2.  Double-check this from PowerShell with:

```
wsl --shutdown # To make sure we stop writing to any potential filesystem
wsl -l -v
```

###### For WSL2

*My test of the following instructions has unfortunately not been successful.  This may be due to a fundamental difference in the way that vhdx files work under WSL2, or it could be the way that they are mounted.  I'm leaving these instructions here in hopes that you or someone can determine what additional actions might make it successful.*

The filesystem is stored in a virtual disk `ext4.vhdx`.  In a default Ubuntu/WSL2 installation, you'll find this under `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited<...>\LocalState\ext4.vhdx`.

Copy this file to another location.  This is the copy that you'll use for attempted recovery.  Probably name it `recovery.vhdx` to avoid any confusion.

The next step depends on your Windows version. This would certainly be easiest under Windows 11.

- For Windows 10 Home, it's going to be tough.  Probably best to copy the vhdx file to a USB drive and see if you can get access to either a Windows 11 (any version) or Windows 10 Pro or higher system.

  That said, it's *possible*, but I've never done this myself.  You would need to:

  - Install a VM, something like VirtualBox or VMWare.  That may require disabling WSL2 (the "Virtual Machine Manager") in "Turn Windows Features on or off" in Settings.
  - Install a Linux guest OS (such as Ubuntu) in the VM
  - Install `libguestfs-tools` which will allow you to mount a vhdx file in Linux (see [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329800/1165986) among others).
  - Mount the vhdx
  - Run recovery tools like those you mention in your question.
- Windows 10 Pro or Higher:  Also not a fun option, but you can install Hyper-V there without disabling WSL2.  Then install a guest Linux OS per the steps above.
- If you are on Windows 11, you can take advantage of the Preview version of WSL, which includes the ability to mount vhdx files directly into WSL2 (note for those reading this later -- It may be released by that time, so you can skip the first step below):

  - Install the *"Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview"* from the Microsoft Store.
  - From PowerShell, issue `wsl --mount <path_to>\recovery.vhdx --vhd --bare`.  Do not do this on your "live" Ubuntu `ext4.vhdx`; only on the backup you've made.  The `--bare` option attaches the disk, but does not mount it.
  - Run your existing Ubuntu instance.
  - Install and run recovery tools such as those you mentioned in your question.
  - Install recovery tools

###### WSL1

The data is stored in an overlay filesystem that exists in the same `LocalState` directory as the WSL2 `ext4.vhdx` mentioned above.

Files in this directory should *not* be accessed directly in Windows, as it [may cause additional data loss](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

However, if a file is deleted from WSL1, it may still be available for undeletion from the NTFS disk.  *Windows* recovery tools should be attempted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful, but mounting the vhdx in the VM does not allow tools such as extundelete to access the data, as far as I can tell.

I instead mounted the vhdx as a second hard drive on my Ubuntu VM, since HyperV can mount vhdx files to the VM. I was able to scan the drive with extundelete this way, since the virtual drive showed up as /dev/sdb. No need for the libguestfs-tools.

My files were not recoverable, unfortunately, but I was able to recover other files from the drive so the approach seems to be sound.